# Theme changing implicitly in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to write a flutter application wHich takes two themes dark and brightness switch case device settings like this:

```
 return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Selectable GridView',
      
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),

      home:HomePage(),
    );
```

with the `Brightness.light` i have no problem but with the `Brightness.dark` it works correctly to some alert and when the app have an alert the alert color didn't change to dark and after the alert all the app change theme and color `primaryColor:Colors.blue` without any code written from me

```
import 'package:backback/Resultat/testclass.dart' as globals;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'package:hardware_buttons/hardware_buttons.dart' as HardwareButtons;
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'ecouteurT.dart';
import 'flashT.dart';

class Boutontest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<Boutontest> {
  String _latestHardwareButtonEvent;

  StreamSubscription<HardwareButtons.VolumeButtonEvent>
      _volumeButtonSubscription;
  StreamSubscription<HardwareButtons.HomeButtonEvent> _homeButtonSubscription;
  StreamSubscription<HardwareButtons.LockButtonEvent> _lockButtonSubscription;
  int a, b, c, d;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      showDialog(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)), //this right here
              child: Container(
                  height: 110,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      child: ListView(
                          children:
                              ListTile.divideTiles(context: context, tiles: [
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            'essayez de appyeez sur les boutons l\'un apres l\'autre et verifiez que tout bouton appyez ets montrez',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: null,
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            'OK',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                          },
                        )
                      ]).toList())))));
    });

    _volumeButtonSubscription =
        HardwareButtons.volumeButtonEvents.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        _latestHardwareButtonEvent = event.toString();
      });
      if (_latestHardwareButtonEvent == 'VolumeButtonEvent.VOLUME_DOWN') {
        b = 0;
      }
      if (_latestHardwareButtonEvent == 'VolumeButtonEvent.VOLUME_UP') {
        c = 0;
      }
    });

    _homeButtonSubscription = HardwareButtons.homeButtonEvents.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        a = 0;
        _latestHardwareButtonEvent = 'HOME_BUTTON';
      });
    });

    _lockButtonSubscription = HardwareButtons.lockButtonEvents.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        d = 0;
        _latestHardwareButtonEvent = 'LOCK_BUTTON';
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _volumeButtonSubscription?.cancel();
    _homeButtonSubscription?.cancel();
    _lockButtonSubscription?.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Hi',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: height * 0.01,
          ),
          Card(
              child: ListTile(
            leading: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor:
                    new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepOrange)),
            title: Text(
              'Detection des Boutons...',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            subtitle: Text('Element 1/1'),
            trailing: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                globals.Data.etatbouton('ignore');

                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Flash()),
                );
              },
              child: Text(
                'Ignore>',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
              ),
            ),
          )),
          Container(
            height: height * 0.02,
          ),
          if (_latestHardwareButtonEvent == 'HOME_BUTTON' || a == 0)
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Le Bouton Home'),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (_latestHardwareButtonEvent == 'LOCK_BUTTON' || d == 0)
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Le Bouton Home'),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (_latestHardwareButtonEvent == 'VolumeButtonEvent.VOLUME_DOWN' ||
              b == 0)
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Le Volume Down'),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (_latestHardwareButtonEvent == 'VolumeButtonEvent.VOLUME_UP' ||
              c == 0)
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Le Volume Up'),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 3.0,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                        30.0) //                 <--- border radius here
                    ),
              ),
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Passer au test suivant',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                   Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {

                    showDialog(

                        barrierDismissible: false,
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                             Dialog(

                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    20.0)), //this right here
                            child: Container(
                                height: 180,
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                    child: ListView(
                                        children: ListTile.divideTiles(
                                            context: context,
                                            tiles: [
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Text(
                                              'Tout les boutons appyez sont montrez',
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            onTap: null,
                                          ),
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Text(
                                              'Oui',
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.deepOrange),
                                            ),
                                            onTap: () {
                                              globals.Data.etatbouton('1');

                                              Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        Flash()),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          ),
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Text(
                                              'Non',
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.deepOrange),
                                            ),
                                            onTap: () {
                                              globals.Data.etatbouton('0');

                                              Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        Flash()),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          )
                                        ]).toList())))));
                  });
                },
              ))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That's the code of one of the alert I need some help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lamp/lamp.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:backback/Resultat/testclass.dart' as globals;

import 'batterieT.dart';
    
class Flash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<Flash> {
  bool _hasFlash = false;
  bool _isOn = false;
  double _intensity = 1.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  initPlatformState() async {
    bool hasFlash = await Lamp.hasLamp;
    print("Device has flash ? $hasFlash");
    setState(() { _hasFlash = hasFlash; });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('hi'),
      ),
      body: Container(

        //
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: height*0.01,
            ),
            Card(child:ListTile(
              leading: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor:
              new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepOrange)),
              title: Text('Detection Connexion et deconnexion des ecouteurs...',style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.deepOrange),),
              subtitle: Text('Element 1/1'),
              trailing: InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  globals.Data.etatkit('ignore');
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Batterie()),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Ignore>',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),),
              ),
            )),
            Container(
              height: height*0.02,
            ),
            Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child:Text(
                  'Veuillez branchez les ecouteurs plusieurs fois tout en verifiant si le texte afffiche correspond a l\'etat reel',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),

       if(_isOn==false)
              new   InkWell(child: Image.asset('assets/flash.jpg'),
                onTap:(){_turnFlash();} ,)      ,
         if(_isOn==true)
              new   InkWell(child: Image.asset('assets/flashO.jpg'),
                onTap:(){_turnFlash();} ,),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell (child:Text('Ne correspond pas',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),)
                    , onTap: (){
                      globals.Data.etatkit('0');
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Batterie()),
                      );
                    },),
                  InkWell(child: Text('Correspond',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),),
                    onTap: (){
                      globals.Data.etatkit('1');
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Batterie()),
                      );
                    },)
                ],
              ),
            )

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );


  }
  Future _turnFlash() async {
    _isOn ? Lamp.turnOff() : Lamp.turnOn(intensity: _intensity);
    var f = await Lamp.hasLamp;
    setState((){
      _hasFlash = f;
      _isOn = !_isOn;
    });
  }

  _intensityChanged(double intensity) {
    Lamp.turnOn(intensity : intensity);
    setState((){
      _intensity = intensity;
    });
  }

}
```

and in this class when the navigator pass to this class I lost dark theme.

Comment: I can't understand please explain clearly.

Comment: when the theme is dark the application run with it until there is an alert the theme change it self and the alert didn't take the theme

Comment: you are showing alert to change the theme in your application, when user change the theme in alert. alert color not changed to dark. is that your problem? otherwise add your full code.

Comment: no but the theme chane his self without any code when the alert is shown and i don't want this to happen

Comment: add your full code brother, because your above code is working correctly.

Comment: i change the question to add full code try to run it and click in the boutton

Comment: for me everything is worked with dark theme correctly. try flutter clean command in terminal and run your application.

Comment: if you give me you mail i can send you a video to make it clearly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214230/discussion-between-msarkrish-and-mohamed-borhene-dhahri).